# How to load large mobi files on a Kindle e-reader?

Tags: kindle, amazon, mobi, send-to-kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

`How do I set [this](https://mva.microsoft.com/ebooks) ebook:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /media/thufir/Kindle/mobi/microsoft/Microsoft_Press_ebook_Windows_10_Support_Secrets_MOBI.mobi 
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 30318271 Jul  7 22:17 /media/thufir/Kindle/mobi/microsoft/Microsoft_Press_ebook_Windows_10_Support_Secrets_MOBI.mobi
thufir@dur:~$
```

to **readable** on a Kindle e-reader, 7th generation?  I've mounted and unmounted the Kindle multiple times.  The file is there, it's the correct size, it's readable from `Calibre` -- not sure what else I can do.

There it is, on the Kindle.  But, not getting picked up.  Other `mobi` files are recognized and readable.  But not this one.

why?

---

this is in the context of:

```
The Kindle Personal Document Service can convert and deliver the following types of documents:
Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)
HTML (.htm, .html)
Text (.txt) documents
Archived documents (zip , x-zip) and compressed archived documents
Mobi book
```

Even after compressing to `.zip` it's too large (at least for gmail).  To re-iterate, the e-books is perfectly readable from `calibre` and so I don't see that it should be a problem with the file being corrupt or unreadable.

I don't seem to be [alone](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/6772/9853) with this general problem of dealing with absurdly large e-book files on the Kindle...

see also:

https://superuser.com/q/1337407/55747

Perhaps convert the `EPUB` to `PDF`, slice into tranches, then re-convert back to `EPUB`?  Sounds like an invitation for everything to go wrong, but *might* work..

Oddly, the `mobi` size seems quite out of whack versus the `EPUB` format:

[image: mobi size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a .mobi file actually includes a couple copies of the book in different formats. Is the .mobi file much larger (like, multiple times) than the epub file? This is the giveaway. The KindleStrip plugin (http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=96903) might help you remove that excess content to bring the file down to a manageable size.